# How to start a for loop at the end of a list and go to the beginning of the list?

Tags: c, list

I have this loop and I wanted to make another loop inside of this one to be able do go from the end of the vector to the beginning of the vector.

```
int troca_7(int vector[], int n)
{
    int temp[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = vector[i];
        printf("%d\n", temp[i]);
    }
```

I have tried this for loop: `for(int j = n - 1; j >= i; j--)`.

Comment: I'm unclear on what the problem is, but note that each of the three clauses in the loop-control block supports *any* valid expression (and the first also supports declarations).  Surely, for example, you could come up with a variation on the particular form you present, in which the index variable starts high and counts down instead of starting low and counting up. Right?

Comment: @Dimmezy It is entirely unclear what you are trying to do. For example why is there  declared the VLA temp?

Comment: let me be more clear like i have this vector: 1 2 3 4 what i want to do is print the original vector and print the inverted vector 4 3 2 1

Comment: @Dimmezy And why does the function has the return type int? What does it try to return?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to arrays as *lists* is very confusing in C: lists usually refer to linked lists of nodes with a `next` pointer.

Here is the recommended idiom to iterate on an array of objects from the last to the first:

```
void print_reverse(const int vector[], size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = n; i-- > 0;)
    {
        printf("%d\n", vector[i]);
    }
}
```

This approach as several advantages:

- the iteration variable is initialized with the number of elements, not `n - 1`.
- the type can be signed or unsigned.  Index variables should have type `size_t` for consistency.
- the number of items can be `0` for an empty array slice.
- the test `i-- > 0` stops the loop when `i` is `0`, and decrements `i` as a side effect.
- the test can also be written `i --> 0` as explained in [this memorable question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c-c).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go through the entire loop backwards with each i iteration, you can do in many ways. Crude way would look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
{
    for(int j = n-1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        printf("backwards: %d\n", vector[j]);
    }
    temp[i] = vector[i];
    printf("%d\n", temp[i]);
}
```

While an elegant way could look like this:

```
for(int i = 0, j = n-1; i < n ; i++, j--)
{
    temp[i] = vector[i];
    printf("%d\n", temp[i]);
    printf("backwards: %d\n", vector[j]);
}
```

You are not limited to one variable in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried this for loop: `for(int j = n - 1; j >= i; j--)`.

just try the following:

```
    for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--)
```

if you stop at the value of `i`, then you are finished before getting the first element.  `i` doesn't exist at the end of the first loop, but you don't show the actual code you used to try the reverse.